# .Net extensibility with QTP

Tags: .net, qtp

I am using QTP v10 and my application is in .Net 3.5. I created the custom server control for TrackBar from the provided document "HP QuickTest professional .Net add-in Extensibility", copied the Configuration.Xml file to SwfConfig file as indicated. Then opened the QuickTest but the test still shows the Click method only and not the SetValue method for the trackbar that is in the .dll created.

The Record and Run settings for Windows applications are for "Record and run test on any open windows based app".

I have the QuickTest open before running the testing application. My Qtpro.exe config file though shows it's running in .Net 2.0 version. But since it's v10 it should support .Net 3.5 I guess.

I have checked everything many times. What could I be missing?